# How do I handle errors or bad requests in my Rails REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a Rails app that includes a JSON API interface. When values are properly specified, the controller handles the happy path just fine and JSON is rendered as output.

However, if there's a problem with the input, an exception is raised and some templates in `rescues` are rendered instead. I'd really just like to return a JSON error along the lines of `{ "error": { "msg": "bad request", "params": ... } }` and the appropriate HTTP status code (e.g. 403 if they weren't authenticated). But I only want this to be applicable to requests against anything in `example.com/api/...`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar case, but I rescued the individual API methods separately because I needed method specific errors, I also could have multiple rescues depending on the error type.

in my application controller, I had a method:

```
def error(status, code, message)
  render :js => {:response_type => "ERROR", :response_code => code, :message => message}.to_json, :status => status
end
```

Then in my API controller

```
def some_method
  ## do stuff
rescue
  error(500, method_specific_error_code, "it all done broke")
  ## additional error notifications here if necessary.
end
```

because I rescue the error, I needed to explicitly call to the hoptoad api.

To handle authentication, I had a `before_filter` for `login_required`

```
def login_required
  error(403, 403, "Not Authenticated") unless authenticated
end
```

And to rescue 404 errors:

```
def render_404
  error(404, 404, "Unknown method")
end
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I too agree with you on this as this is the best way to render custom errors also for different actions

Comment: Just a note, but you could instead do `render :json => {...}` rather than `render :js => {...}`

Answer (score 4):

How about an `around_filter` on your api controller. Something like

```
around_filter :my_filter

private
def my_filter
  begin
    yield
  rescue
    render :js => ...
  end
end
```